# Tests using .Count() on Lists

Tags: c#, performance, array

The test

```
PublicQuestion_ComplexTest
```

is taking around 1600ms (1.6 seconds) to run, but used to take 92ms. I have a feeling this is because of recent code changes that include `.Count()` in many places within these 2 functions:

```
RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations
```

and

```
CropNumbersToBeWithinAllowances
```

The goal is for the code to run much more efficiently, hopefully under 100ms. Any suggestions?

```
    [Test] 
    public void PublicQuestion_SimpleTest()
    {
        // Fixed values
        var group1 = new int[] { 1 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 4 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 6 };

        // Selection values
        var group4 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var group5 = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        var group7 = new int[] { 1, 5 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1, //1
            group1, //1
            group2, //4
            group3, //6
            group4, //1, 2, 3
            group5, //3, 4
            group6, //3, 4, 5
            group7  //1, 5
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
            {1, 999},
            {2, 1},
            {3, 2},
            {4, 2},
            {5, 1},
            {6, 1}
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();
        watch.Stop();
        Assert.AreEqual(14, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 22); //7ms



        #region string maker
        List<string> combinationStringed = new List<string>();
        foreach (var group in results)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var number in group)
            {
                sb.Append(number + ".");
            }
            combinationStringed.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        StringBuilder sbOrderedResults = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var result in combinationStringed.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            sbOrderedResults.Append(result + "|");
        }
        string x1 = sbOrderedResults.ToString().Replace(".|", "|");
        #endregion

        Assert.AreEqual(x1, "1.1.1.1.3.3.4.6|1.1.1.1.3.4.4.6|1.1.1.1.3.4.5.6|1.1.1.1.4.4.5.6|1.1.1.2.3.3.4.6|1.1.1.2.3.4.4.6|1.1.1.2.3.4.5.6|1.1.1.2.4.4.5.6|1.1.1.3.3.4.4.6|1.1.1.3.3.4.5.6|1.1.1.3.4.4.5.6|1.1.2.3.3.4.5.6|1.1.2.3.4.4.5.6|1.1.3.3.4.4.5.6|");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test] 
    public void PublicQuestion_SimpleMoreCombinationsTest()
    {
        // Fixed values
        var group1 = new int[] { 1 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 4 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 6 };

        // Selection values
        var group4 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var group5 = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        var group7 = new int[] { 1, 5 };
        var group8 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1,
            group1,
            group2,
            group3,
            group4,
            group4,
            group4,
            group4,
            group4,
            group5,
            group6,
            group7,
            group8
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
             {1, 999},
             {2, 5},
             {3, 5},
             {4, 999},
             {5, 999},
             {6, 999},
             {7, 999},
             {8, 999}
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();



        #region string maker
        List<string> combinationStringed = new List<string>();
        foreach (var group in results)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var number in group)
            {
                sb.Append(number + ".");
            }
            combinationStringed.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        StringBuilder sbOrderedResults = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var result in combinationStringed.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            sbOrderedResults.Append(result + "|");
        }
        string x1 = sbOrderedResults.ToString().Replace(".|", "|");
        #endregion

        string x2 = x1;


        watch.Stop();
        Assert.AreEqual(684, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 535); //265 //28ms
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test] 
    public void PublicQuestion_ComplexTest()
    {
        // Fixed values
        var group1 = new int[] { 1 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 4 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 6 };

        // Selection values
        var group4 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var group5 = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        var group7 = new int[] { 1, 5 };
        var group8 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1,
            group1,
            group2,
            group3,
            group4,
            group4,
            group5,
            group5,
            group5,
            group6,
            group6,
            group6,
            group7,
            group7,
            group7,
            group8
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
            {1, 999},
            {2, 1},
            {3, 5},
            {4, 5},
            {5, 7},
            {6, 999},
            {7, 999},
            {8, 999}
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();
        watch.Stop();


        #region string maker
        List<string> combinationStringed = new List<string>();
        foreach (var group in results)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var number in group)
            {
                sb.Append(number + ".");
            }
            combinationStringed.Add(sb.ToString());
        }
        StringBuilder sbOrderedResults = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var result in combinationStringed.OrderBy(x => x))
        {
            sbOrderedResults.Append(result + "|");
        }
        string x1 = sbOrderedResults.ToString().Replace(".|", "|");
        #endregion
        string combinationsStringed = x1;


        Assert.AreEqual(852, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 2000); //1625 
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test] 
    public void RestrictedTest1()
    {
        // Fixed values
        var group1 = new int[] { 1 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 4 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 6 };

        // Selection values
        var group4 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var group5 = new int[] { 3, 4 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 3, 4, 5 };
        var group7 = new int[] { 1, 5 };
        var group8 = new int[] { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1,
            group1,
            group2,
            group3,
            group4,
            group4,
            group5,
            group5,
            group5,
            group6,
            group6,
            group6,
            group7,
            group7,
            group7,
            group8
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
                {1, 999},
                {2, 1},
                {3, 0},
                {4, 0},
                {5, 0},
                {6, 999},
                {7, 999},
                {8, 999}
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();
        watch.Stop();
        Assert.AreEqual(6, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 112); //19 //2ms
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test] 
    public void RestrictedTest2()
    {
        // Fixed values
        var group1 = new int[] { 4 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 6 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 7 };

        // Selection values
        var group4 = new int[] { 50, 51 };
        var group5 = new int[] { 3, 8, 12 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 42, 43 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1, //4
            group1, //4
            group2, //6
            group2, //6
            group2, //6
            group3, //7
            group3, //7
            group3, //7
            group4, //50, 51
            group4, //50, 51
            group5, //3, 8, 12
            group5, //3, 8, 12
            group6, //42, 43
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
            {3, 2},
            {4, 1},
            {6, 1},
            {7, 0},
            {8, 1},
            {12, 0},
            {42, 0},
            {43, 0},
            {50, 2},
            {51, 2},
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();
        watch.Stop();
        Assert.AreEqual(6, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 113); //16 //3ms
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test]
    public void HugeNumbersTest()
    {
        // Fixed values
        int largestInt32 = Int32.MaxValue;
        var group1 = new int[] { 5 };
        var group2 = new int[] { 456789 };
        var group3 = new int[] { 982981929 };
        var group4 = new int[] { largestInt32 };

        // Selection values
        var group5 = new int[] { 43234234, 1111511, 77878778 };
        var group6 = new int[] { 24352, 44, 981981980 };
        var group7 = new int[] { largestInt32, 44, 981981980, 77878778 };

        var groups = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            group1, 
            group1, 
            group2, 
            group2, 
            group3,
            group3,
            group4,
            group4,
            group5,
            group5,
            group6,
            group6,
            group7,
            group7,
            group7
        };

        var allowances = new Dictionary<int, int>()
        {
            {5, 999},
            {456789, 999},
            {982981929, 999},
            {largestInt32, 999},
            {43234234, 999},
            {1111511, 999},
            {77878778, 999},
            {24352, 999},
            {44, 999},
            {981981980, 999},
        };

        var finder = new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(groups, allowances);
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        IList<IList<int>> results = finder.GetAll();
        watch.Stop();
        Assert.AreEqual(540, results.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 500); //120 //8ms
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format(
            "{0:#,##0} combinations found in {1:#,##0.000} seconds.",
            results.Count,
            watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0));
    }

    [Test]
    public void RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinationsTest()
    {
        var combo1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7 };
        var combo2 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
        var combo3 = new int[] { 1, 1,    3, 4, 5 }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo4 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3,    5 }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo5 = new int[] {    1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo6 = new int[] { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4    }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo7 = new int[] {    1, 2,       5 }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo8 = new int[] {       2,       5 }; //duplicate of combo2
        var combo9 = new int[] {       2          }; //duplicate of combo1 or combo2
        var combo10 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 5 }; //duplicate of combo1
        var combo11 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 6 }; //duplicate of combo1
        var combo12 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 7 }; //duplicate of combo1
        var combo13 = new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 8 };
        var combo14 = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 }; //duplicate of combo1
        var combo15 = new int[] { 0, 1, 4, 5 };
        var combo16 = new int[] { 1, 1, 4, 5 }; //duplicate of combo2 or combo3
        var combo17 = new int[] { 1, 1, 4, 5, 6 }; 

        var allCombos = new List<IList<int>>()
        {
            combo1,
            combo2,
            combo3,
            combo4,
            combo5,
            combo6,
            combo7,
            combo8,
            combo9,
            combo10,
            combo11,
            combo12,
            combo13,
            combo14,
            combo15,
            combo16,
            combo17
        };

        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //testing to see how long it takes for this to run
            var ignoredResults = (new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder()).RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations(allCombos);
        }
        var results = (new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder()).RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations(allCombos);

        watch.Stop();

        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 25); //14





        Assert.AreEqual(5, results.Count());

        string resultsToString = string.Join("", results.Select(x => string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.ToString()).ToArray()) + "|" ).ToArray());
        Assert.AreEqual(resultsToString, "1,2,2,2,2,2,5,6,7|1,1,2,3,4,5|2,2,2,2,8|1,1,4,5,6|0,1,4,5|");
    }


    public class PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder
    {
        public IList<IList<int>> Groups { get; private set; }
        public IDictionary<int, int> Allowances { get; private set; }

        public PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder()
        {
        }
        public PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder(IList<IList<int>> groups, IDictionary<int, int> allowances)
        {
            // Check if groups are specified
            if (groups == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("groups");
            }

            // Copy the list of groups, removing any restricted values
            this.Groups = CopyGroupsWithoutRestrictedValues(groups, allowances);

            // Check if optional allowances are specified
            if (allowances != null && allowances.Count > 0)
            {
                this.Allowances = allowances;
            }
        }

        public IList<IList<int>> GetAll()
        {
            var combinations = new List<IList<int>>();

            if (this.Groups.Count > 0)
            {
                var foundHashes = new Dictionary<int, IList<IList<int>>>();
                var currentCombination = new int[this.Groups.Count];
                int groupIndex = 0;
                FindPermutations(currentCombination, groupIndex, combinations, foundHashes);
            }

            combinations = RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations(combinations);

            return combinations;
        }

        private List<IList<int>> RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations(List<IList<int>> combinations)
        {
            if (combinations.Any() == false)
            {
                return new List<IList<int>>();
            }

            //it is assumed, due to previous code that generates the combinations, that no 2 combinations can be the exact same (1,2,2,3 vs 2,1,2,3 = same)
            var newCombinations = new List<IList<int>>();

            var sortedCombinations = (from w in combinations orderby w.Count descending select w);

            int maxLength = sortedCombinations.First().Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < sortedCombinations.Count(); i++)
            {
                var combination = sortedCombinations.Skip(i).First();
                if (combination.Count() == maxLength)
                {
                    newCombinations.Add(combination);
                    continue;
                }

                bool exists = false;
                foreach (var newCombo in newCombinations)
                {
                    if (LargerComboContainsSmallerCombo(newCombo, combination))
                    {
                        exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (exists == false)
                {
                    newCombinations.Add(combination);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            return newCombinations;
        }

        private bool LargerComboContainsSmallerCombo(IList<int> largerList, IList<int> smallerList)
        {
            if (largerList.Count() == smallerList.Count())
            {
                return false;
            }

            var distinctNumbersInSmaller = smallerList.Distinct();

            foreach (var number in distinctNumbersInSmaller)
            {
                if (largerList.Where(x => x == number).Count() < smallerList.Where(x => x == number).Count())
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private void FindPermutations(int[] currentCombination, int groupIndex,
            IList<IList<int>> combinations, IDictionary<int, IList<IList<int>>> foundHashes)
        {
            int maxGroupIndex = this.Groups.Count - 1;

            for (int valueIndex = 0, valueCount = this.Groups[groupIndex].Count; valueIndex < valueCount; ++valueIndex)
            {
                currentCombination[groupIndex] = this.Groups[groupIndex][valueIndex];

                if (groupIndex == maxGroupIndex)
                {
                    AddCandidateCombination(currentCombination, combinations, foundHashes);
                }
                else
                {
                    FindPermutations((int[])currentCombination.Clone(), groupIndex + 1, combinations, foundHashes);
                }
            }
        }

        private bool AddCandidateCombination(int[] currentCombination,
            IList<IList<int>> combinations, IDictionary<int, IList<IList<int>>> foundHashes)
        {
            currentCombination = CropNumbersToBeWithinAllowances(currentCombination);

            if (currentCombination.Count() == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }

            int currentHash = GetCombinationHash(currentCombination);
            IList<IList<int>> extantCombinations;
            bool hashCollision = foundHashes.TryGetValue(currentHash, out extantCombinations);
            int[] sortedValues = (int[])currentCombination.Clone();
            Array.Sort(sortedValues);

            if (hashCollision)
            {
                bool combinationFound = false;

                foreach (var extantCombination in extantCombinations)
                {
                    combinationFound = CompareCombinations(sortedValues, extantCombination);

                    if (combinationFound)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (combinationFound)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (hashCollision)
            {
                extantCombinations.Add(sortedValues);
            }
            else
            {
                var newCombinationList = new List<IList<int>>();
                newCombinationList.Add(sortedValues);
                foundHashes.Add(currentHash, newCombinationList);
            }

            combinations.Add(sortedValues);
            return true;
        }

        private static int GetCombinationHash(int[] combination)
        {
            int hash = 1;

            unchecked
            {
                for (int index = 0, length = combination.Length; index < length; ++index)
                {
                    int operand = combination[index] + 1;
                    hash += operand * operand * operand * operand * operand;
                }
            }

            return hash;
        }

        private static bool CompareCombinations(int[] newCombination, IList<int> extantCombination)
        {
            if (newCombination.Length != extantCombination.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }

            for (int valueIndex = 0, length = newCombination.Length; valueIndex < length; ++valueIndex)
            {
                if (newCombination[valueIndex] != extantCombination[valueIndex])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        private int[] CropNumbersToBeWithinAllowances(int[] currentCombination)
        {
            if (this.Allowances == null)
            {
                return currentCombination;
            }

            List<int> newCombination = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombination.Length; i++)
            {
                int currentValue = currentCombination[i];

                if (newCombination.Where(x => x == currentValue).Count() >= this.Allowances[currentValue])
                {
                    continue;
                }

                newCombination.Add(currentValue);
            }

            return newCombination.ToArray();
        }

        private static IList<IList<int>> CopyGroupsWithoutRestrictedValues(IList<IList<int>> groups, IDictionary<int, int> allowances)
        {
            IList<IList<int>> sourceGroups;

            if (allowances != null && allowances.Count > 0)
            {
                var restrictedValues = new HashSet<int>();

                foreach (var allowance in allowances)
                {
                    if (allowance.Value < 1)
                    {
                        restrictedValues.Add(allowance.Key);
                    }
                }

                if (restrictedValues.Count > 0)
                {
                    sourceGroups = new List<IList<int>>();

                    foreach (var valueGroup in groups)
                    {
                        if (valueGroup != null && valueGroup.Count > 0)
                        {
                            sourceGroups.Add(RemoveRestrictedValues(valueGroup, restrictedValues));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sourceGroups = groups;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                sourceGroups = groups;
            }

            var prunedGroups = new List<IList<int>>();

            foreach (var valueGroup in sourceGroups)
            {
                if (valueGroup != null && valueGroup.Count > 0)
                {
                    prunedGroups.Add(valueGroup);
                }
            }

            return prunedGroups;
        }

        private static IList<int> RemoveRestrictedValues(IList<int> valueGroup, ICollection<int> restrictedValues)
        {
            var prunedGroup = new List<int>();

            foreach (int value in valueGroup)
            {
                if (!restrictedValues.Contains(value))
                {
                    prunedGroup.Add(value);
                }
            }

            return prunedGroup;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only glanced at your code, but you should use `.Count` (property) on `List<T>`. The `.Count()` method works off the `IEnumerable<T>` and iterates the entire collection. You need to reduce the number of times you're iterating an `IEnumerable<T>` - call `.ToList()` *once* and use the list's `Count` property instead.

Comment: And as far as I know using the `Count()` on  `IEnumerable<T>` will utilize the *lazy evaluation* and the results of it wouldn't be that trusted.

Comment: Just a note, Enumerable.Count() is optimized for `ICollection<T>` to use the `.Count` member property. I'm not worried about its usage on actual lists. On other enumerables (query results, etc.), it could still be an issue.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram indeed! that's funny, I [was just told exactly that](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/indexordefault-that-functions-like-firstordefault/54577#comment95226_54577)! You bet I've learned something today! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Documentation

This is quite a lot of code. I can tell you've put some effort into the naming of methods, but comments describing the purpose of each would go a long way.

Imagine that you're looking at this code for the first time -- is it clear to you what the output of a call to `GetAll` should be? What conditions will hold on the result?

For example, I believe the following are true (correct me if I'm wrong) and worth documenting:

```
// For each `result` in the returned value, it is true that
//    result.Distinct().All(x => result.Count(y => y == x) <= allowances[x]).

// For each `result` in the returned value, it is true that
//     result.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(result).

// For each distinct `x` and `y` in the returned value, it is false that
//     x.SequenceEqual(y).
```

## Use the framework

It looks like you're not using the .NET framework to its full extent. Let's look at a couple of examples.

```
private static IList<int> RemoveRestrictedValues(IList<int> valueGroup, ICollection<int> restrictedValues)
{
    var prunedGroup = new List<int>();

    foreach (int value in valueGroup)
    {
        if (!restrictedValues.Contains(value))
        {
            prunedGroup.Add(value);
        }
    }

    return prunedGroup;
}
```

Could be rewritten as

```
private static IList<int> RemoveRestrictedValues(IList<int> valueGroup, ICollection<int> restrictedValues)
{
    return valueGroup.Where(value => !restrictedValues.Contains(value))
        .ToList();
}
```

If the original version has significant performance benefits, document it as such to make it clear to the reader that that's why you wrote it that way. For example,

```
// PERFORMANCE: The foreach version is significantly faster
// than the valueGroup.Where(...).ToList() alternative.
```

In fact, I think both `CopyGroupsWithoutRestrictedValues` and `RemoveRestrictedValues` can be replaced by one method:

```
private static List<List<int>> CopyGroupsWithoutRestrictedValues(IList<IList<int>> groups, IDictionary<int, int> allowances)
{
    return groups.Select(group => group.Where(x => allowances[x] > 0).ToList())
        .Where(group => group.Any())
        .ToList();
}
```

In your tests, the string maker region can be replaced with this:

```
string.Join(
    "|",
    results.Select(result => string.Join(".", result)).OrderBy(result => result));
```

The method `AddCandidateCombination` could probably be replaced by a call to [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), with `GetCombinationHash` and `CompareCombinations` being the basis for the `IEqualityComparer<int>` argument (see code below if this isn't clear).

## API

Why is there a parameterless constructor? What is the expected result of `new PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder().GetAll()`?

Why have a constructor at all? What can I do with an instance of `PickOneNumberFromEachGroupCombinationFinder` other than repeatedly call `GetAll`, returning the same result? I think it would be fine to replace `GetAll` with a static method, so client code might read

```
var combinations = CombinationFinder.PickOneFromEachGroup(groups, allowances);
```

**Edit** This code passes all tests and is significantly faster on my machine.

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<int>> PickOneFromEachGroup(
    IList<IList<int>> groups,
    Dictionary<int, int> allowed)
{
    var combinations = GetCombinationsHelper(new int[groups.Count], groups.Count, 0, groups, 0, allowed)
        .Distinct(new ArrayComparer());
    return RemoveSmallerCombinations(combinations);
}

private static IEnumerable<int[]> GetCombinationsHelper(
    int[] result,
    int resultLength,
    int resultIndex,
    IList<IList<int>> groups,
    int groupIndex,
    Dictionary<int, int> allowed)
{
    // Base case: the array is full.
    if (resultIndex == resultLength)
    {
        var copy = new int[resultLength];
        Array.Copy(result, copy, resultLength);
        Array.Sort(copy);
        yield return copy;
        yield break;
    }

    var nextGroupIndex = groupIndex + 1;
    var nextResultIndex = resultIndex + 1;
    var foundAny = false;
    foreach (var x in groups[groupIndex])
    {
        if (allowed[x] <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        foundAny = true;

        result[resultIndex] = x;
        allowed[x]--;
        foreach (var combination in GetCombinationsHelper(result, resultLength, nextResultIndex, groups, nextGroupIndex, allowed))
        {
            yield return combination;
        }

        allowed[x]++;
    }

    // No elements in groups[groupIndex] had a positive allowance,
    // so skip this group.
    if (!foundAny)
    {
        foreach (var combination in GetCombinationsHelper(result, resultLength - 1, resultIndex, groups, nextGroupIndex, allowed))
        {
            yield return combination;
        }
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<int[]> RemoveSmallerCombinations(IEnumerable<int[]> combinations)
{
    using (var enumerator = combinations.OrderByDescending(combination => combination.Length).GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var current = enumerator.Current;
        var maxLength = current.Length;
        yield return current;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            current = enumerator.Current;
            if (current.Length != maxLength)
            {
                yield break;
            }

            yield return current;
        }
    }
}

private class ArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] != y[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var result = 17;
            foreach (var x in obj)
            {
                result = result * 31 + x.GetHashCode();
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good feedback, much appreciated! Unfortunately the code suggestion you provided: 2 Tests fail, both are returning 0 results: `RestrictedTest1` and `RestrictedTest2` -- do you have any suggestions on how to rework your suggested answer to allow for all provided tests to pass?

Comment: Updated the `RestrictedTest1` and `RestrictedTest2` to include more precise expected results -- refer to Assert.AreEqual(x1, ...

Comment: @SED I've updated with code that passes the tests.

Comment: Verified: all tests pass, speed is improved. The ComplexTest takes ~125ms -- THANK YOU! :)

Answer (score 5):

In `CropNumbersToBeWithinAllowances()` you do

```
newCombination.Where(x => x == currentValue).Count()
```

inside the `for` loop. `newCombination` is of type `List<T>` so calling `Count()` on that would fall back to `Count` (as  Anthony Pegram already mentioned in the comments). However, the `Where` query turns that into an `IEnumerable<T>` so `Count()` will indeed iterate the whole enumerable in every iteration of the loop!

Instead keep track of the *remaining* allowances by decrementing the `Allowances` dictionary (or a copy if you need to keep it). Something like this (untested):

```
private int[] CropNumbersToBeWithinAllowances(int[] currentCombination)
{
    if (this.Allowances == null)
        return currentCombination;

    // Create a copy from the this.Allowances dictionary
    Dictionary<int, int> remainingAllowances = new Dictionary<int, int>(this.Allowances);

    List<int> newCombination = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < currentCombination.Length; i++)
    {
        int currentValue = currentCombination[i];

        if(remainingAllowances[currentValue]==0)
            continue;

        newCombination.Add(currentValue);
        remainingAllowances[currentValue]--;
    }

    return newCombination.ToArray();
}
```

### Update

In the method with the long name you do

```
var sortedCombinations = (from w in combinations orderby w.Count descending select w);

int maxLength = sortedCombinations.First().Count();
for (int i = 0; i < sortedCombinations.Count(); i++)
{
    var combination = sortedCombinations.Skip(i).First();
    if (combination.Count() == maxLength)
    {
        ...
```

`sortedCombinations` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`. That means that you enumerate the whole enumerable *every time* you call `Count()` and `Skip()` inside the loop!

You could cast the `sortedCombinations` enumerable to something like an array or a list and use `Length` or `Count` instead of `Count()` (as Frank suggested). But since you are only using the loop variable to access elements of the enumerable in order you could as well just use foreach:

```
var sortedCombinations = (from w in combinations orderby w.Count descending select w);

// Note: IList<T> is an ICollection<T> so IList<T>.Count() will fall back to the Count property
int maxLength = sortedCombinations.First().Count();
foreach(var combination in sortedCombinations)
{
    if (combination.Count() == maxLength) // see note above
    {
        ...
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking a bit at it, I managed to cut the runtime roughly in half by adding a `.ToArray()` in `RemoveSmallerLengthNumberListsThatContainSameNumberCombinationAsLargerLengthCombinations` on the `sortedCombinations` query like so:

```
var sortedCombinations = (from w in combinations orderby w.Count descending select w).ToArray();`
```

When using the `Count()` as the loop condition, and then doing a `Skip` + `First`, you are effectively sorting this collection `Count`*2 times because of deferred execution.

Comment: Very good suggestion! Yes on my end it cuts it in half as well, down from ~1400ms to ~600ms :)  That "for" syntax that was badly written was my attempt to follow someone elses advice that you should "always use for instead of foreach for efficiency": I suppose that only helps if you write it a certain way ;)