# IndexOrDefault that functions like FirstOrDefault

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I don't know why this is not in the .NET Library, but I need to be able to use an index against a list and not have it throw an exception if it is outside the bounds of the list.

This is what I came up with:

```
public static class LinqHelpers
{
    public static TListType IndexOrDefault<TListType>(this List<TListType> list,
                                                      int index)
    {
        var count = list.Count();           
        if (index > count -1)
            return default(TListType);              
        if (index < 0)
            return default(TListType);          
        return list[index];
    }
}
```

This is my test:

```
List<string> somelist = new List<string> {"B", "A", "Q", "a", "t", "h"};
for (int i = -100; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(somelist .IndexOrDefault(i)); 
}
```

I would appreciate any advice on missing error handling or if I am reinventing an already existing feature.  I also would not mind advice on a way to use an IEnumerable instead of a List with out iterating the IEnumerable more than once.

Comment: If the `Count()` _were_ an issue (it isn't, see below) you could move the `if(index<0) return default(T)` above that to avoid calculating the count where you don't actually need it.

Comment: _IndexOrDefault_ reads as if you want to get the index of an item, or a default index if the item is not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> public static TListType IndexOrDefault<TListType>(this List<TListType> list, int index)
> ```

You're extending a concrete type, and the type parameter's name is misleading - it's not the type of the *list*, it's the type of its *items*. I'd just call it `T`. `IList<T>` calls it `T`, so I don't see a problem with `T` ;)

You should be extending an *interface*, in this case probably an `IEnumerable<T>`, like LINQ extension methods do.

> ```
> var count = list.Count();
> ```

You're *iterating* the `List<T>` through its `IEnumerable<T>` interface (doesn't apply to `List<T>` because a `List<T>` is also an `ICollection<T>` [see @svick's comment below](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54574/indexordefault-that-functions-like-firstordefault/54577?noredirect=1#comment95226_54577), but in other cases that would be \$O(n)\$ already), and you haven't tried to find anything yet! A `List<T>` doesn't need to be iterated to retrieve its count, just use the `Count` property getter, like this:

```
var count = list.Count;
```

Actually this whole block:

> ```
>     var count = list.Count();           
>     if (index > count -1)
>         return default(T);              
>     if (index < 0)
>         return default(T);
>     return list[index];
> ```

Could be simplified to:

```
if (index > list.Count - 1 || index < 0)
{
    return default(T)
}

return list[index];
```

---

But that's still extending a `List<T>`. You're going to want to extend `IEnumerable<T>` instead... but the method you're implementing already exists in `System.Linq`:

```
public static T IndexOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int index)
{
    return source.ElementAtOrDefault(index);
}
```

You're duplicating the functionality of the `IEnumerable<T>.ElementAtOrDefault` extension method.

Comment: `Count()` actually isn't \$O(n)\$ for collections that implement `ICollection<T>`, because it just accesses their `Count`. But the advice to prefer `Count` over `Count()` still stands.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Right, I should have checked how did it render.

Comment: I feel like a method named `IndexOrDefault` should throw an exception with a negative index. To me, the name implies it will provide a value at a specified index if it *exists*. An invalid index is still an invalid index though. Edit - Just checked, and it seems `ElementAtOrDefault` doesn't care about negative indexes...still feels wrong to me though.